# DataBinding to a Control

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, binding

I'm using Silverlight with the MVVM.

I have a simple `LoginControl` bound to a `LoginControlViewModel`.  The `LoginControl` is created and added to my `MasterPage`.

When the user logs in to my app, by pressing the Login BUtton on the `LoginControl`, the `LoginControlViewModel` sends an event back to the `MasterPageControlViewModel`.  At this point the `MasterPageControlViewModel.LoginVisible` property is set to `False`.

The problem i am having is with XAML of the `MasterPageView`, since I dont know how to bind the LoginControl to the `MasterPageControlViewModel.LoginVisible` property.  The below doesn't work.

```
<Controls:Login x:Name="LoginControl" Style="{StaticResource LoginControlStyle}"
    Visibility="{Binding LoginControlVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}" />
```

The output window states the following:

> > System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'LoginControlVisibility'    property not found on 'Silverlight.Controls.LoginControlViewModel' 'Silverlight.Controls.LoginControlViewModel' (HashCode=43749873). BindingExpression: Path='LoginControlVisibility' DataItem='Silverlight.Controls.LoginControlViewModel' (HashCode=43749873); target element is 'Controls.Login' (Name='LoginControl'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility')

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, and I see your property is on a different ViewModel than what the control has for it's DataContext.

What I've done in the past is place the `LoginControl` in another container (say a `Border` or `StackPanel`) and then you can bind the `Visibility` of that panel to your property. That way the DataContext of the `LoginControl` stays the `LoginControlViewModel` and the visibility binding is simple.

**Edit**: Turns out below method is not supported in Silverlight.

Or you can have a complicated binding on the `LoginControl` that looks at its parents `DataContext`:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.LoginVisible, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MasterPage},
         Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}}"
```

Also isn't your property called `LoginVisible`  not `LoginControlVisibility` as you have in your binding? Or was that a typo just in the question?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typeo should be LoginControlVisibility.  I think to solve it i need to access the relative source DataContext in the binding.  I am reading this is not supported in Silverlight

Comment: I'm not sure if it's supported in silverlight, but try it. This makes it look like it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @caa ok. It would just go with my first suggestion of binding the visibility on the container.